# Running python script from Terraform local-exec provisioner

Tags: terraform

**Versions**

- VS Code: v1.74.3
- Python: v3.9.1
- Terraform v1.3.6

**Setup**

I have the following folder structure

```bash
.
├── main.tf
└── scripts
    └── my_script.py
```

main.tf:

```hcl
locals {
  python = (substr(pathexpand("~"), 0, 1) == "/") ? "python3" : "python.exe"
}

resource "null_resource" "custom_objects" {
  for_each = local.custom_objects

  triggers = {
    name        = each.key
  }

  provisioner "local-exec" {
    command = <<-EOT
      python3 -m my_script '{"key_1": "value_1"}'
    EOT
    interpreter = [
      local.python
    ]
    working_dir = "${path.module}/scripts"
  }
}
```

./scripts/my_script.py:

```py
if __name__ == '__main__':
    print('my_script executed.')
```

**Problem**
When I run `terraform plan/apply` I get the following error:

> Error running command 'python3 -m my_script '{"key_1": "value_1"}'
> │ ': exit status 2. Output: /home_path/.pyenv/versions/3.9.1/bin/python3: can't open file '/path_to_repo/scripts/python3 -m my_script '{"key_1": "value_1"}'
> │ ': [Errno 2] No such file or directory

**Qeustions**

- Why is local-exec provisioner unable to find my script given the error message shows the absolute path to it?
- What should the configuration be such that I can execute a python script as a module from the local-exec provisioner?

Comment: Does `my_script.py` work if you provide that instead of only `my_script`?

Comment: @MarkoE, nope.  I get the same error, but with `my_script.py` in place of `my_script` in the error output.

Comment: And what about `${path.root}`?

Comment: Nope, same error.  Changing `path.module` to `path.root` doesn't change the error message at all which is odd.

Comment: Which OS are you using?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It seems when the `interpreter` argument is provided it is appended to the path defined in the `working_dir`, which explains this error:

> '/path_to_repo/scripts/python3 -m my_script '{"key_1": "value_1"}'

As you can see, the path ends with `python3` which probably is not there.

I managed to get the result using the following syntax:

```
resource "null_resource" "custom_objects" {
  for_each = local.custom_objects

  triggers = {
     name = each.key
  }

  provisioner "local-exec" {
    command = <<-EOT
      ${local.python} -m my_script '{"key_1": "value_1"}'
    EOT
    working_dir = "${path.module}/scripts" # works with ${path.root} as well
  }
}
```

You might also find [`terraform_data`](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/resources/terraform-data#example-usage-null_resource-replacement) as a good replacement for the `null_resource`.